# Resetting Attribute to default after script is done

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change my attribute to default after i have changed it via jQuery but i cannot find any jQuery API for it.

```
 jQuery("#video")
 .attr("src","http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
 jQuery(".video").get(0).play();
 jQuery(".fullscreen").click(function(){
 jQuery(this).removeClass("is-video-active");
 jQuery(".video").get(0).pause();
 //reset the attribute to default
 jQuery("#video").attr('src','');
```

here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/hdas2012/pen/apLZya)

Edit

Now that I found `jQuery("#video").attr('src','');` but it removes the first video from age, leaving a white empty space.

Comment: `$('#video').attr('src', '');`

Comment: try caching the previous attr with `var prev_src = jQuery('#video').attr('src');` and then you can reset to `jQuery('#video').attr('src', prev_src);`

Comment: @ramabarca That makes my src empty.

Comment: @Nofel, but there is a _default_ value for the `src` attr?

Comment: @ramabarca I updated the link with a codepen

Comment: ah ok, in your code the selector `#video` does'nt exists. Maybe trying with the selector `var prev_src = jQuery('video#bgvid source').attr('src');`

Comment: @ramabarca tried that but it takes out the src on the video, leaving it blank.

Answer (score 0):

You could init the `src` attribute using :

```
jQuery("#video").attr('src','');
//Or
jQuery("#video").prop('src','');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes my src blank like removes it.

Comment: Add you HTML code please, I suggest to add `data-*` attribute that will contain the original `src`..